# Url Redirection error if url contains reserved characters

Tags: http, url, redirect, httpclient, mediawiki

I am trying to access particular url

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("abc.com", 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "Passwd"));

HTTPHelper http = new HTTPHelper(httpclient);

http.get("http://abc.com/**aaa**/w/api.php?param=timestamp%7Cuser&format=xml");
```

where %7C= |

which is redirecting me to the following url internally

```
http://abc.com/**bbb**/w/api.php?param=timestamp%257Cuser&format=xml
```

and because of that I am not able to get the correct output...

```
| ==>%7C

%==> %25

%7C == %257C
```

I want query to be `timestamp|user`
but because of circular redirection it is changed into `timestamp%7Cuser`
Is there any way to avoid this??

I wrote my own Custom Redirect Strategy also

```
httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
            public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                boolean isRedirect = false;
                try {
                    isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
                    LOG.info(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    LOG.info(request.getRequestLine().getUri().replaceAll("%25", "%"));
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!isRedirect) {
                    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return isRedirect;
            }
        });
```

But I am not sure how to replace %25C with %7C from redirected url

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the site's URL rewrite rules are simply broken.  If it's not your site, you may want to contact its maintainers and inform them about the issue.

In the mean time, is there some reason why you can't simply use the target URLs (i.e. `http://abc.com/**bbb**/w/api.php?...`) directly, avoiding the redirect?

Comment: thanks IImari for the response...but i dont have control over the site..and i am building the url from information coming from the site which is giving me the url http://abc.com/**aaa**/.... Can I do something by writing my own custom redirect handler ??

Comment: You could try that, but honestly, you'd just be writing a kluge to work around the particular way in which that specific site is broken. Your custom handler would be unlikely to be useful for any other site (and it might even break some of them), and there's no guarantee that it'd even keep working if the broken site ever changes their rewrite rules. So, given that you'd be implementing a site-specific hack anyway, why not just add some code so that, when the site tells you to use `abc.com/**aaa**`, you replace it with `abc.com/**bbb**`?

Answer (score 0):

Does just `http.get("http://abc.com/**aaa**/w/api.php?param=timestamp|user&format=xml");`
 work?

What's your meaning "redirecting me to the following url internally"? It's like that your url are encoded again. Can you post code in HTTPHelper? My below test code work correctly.

Client Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/test/myservlet?param=timestamp%7Cuser&format=xml");
client.execute(get);
```

Servlet Code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String param = request.getParameter("param"); //get timestamp|user
        String format = request.getParameter("format");

    }
```

Comment: Nope. It is throwing IllegalArgumentException

Comment: The host "abc.com/**aaa**" is moved to some other server permanently. I am getting 301 response from it and then it is redirected to "abc.com/**bbb**". At the time of redirection url gets encoded again. I am trying to intercept the redirection and do again url decoding in the middle. But not able to do so..